# Model/View of threads results

Tags: multithreading, qt, qt4

I would like manage a set of application requirements. Each requirement have a state (Accepted, Rejected, InProgress), and a message state. Some toolbuttons have to be enabled just if all the requirements are accepted.

All the requirements are viewed in a tableview (two colums : name and state message), with an icon state for each line.

A requirement is checked by a separated worker. I do this with QtConcurrent/QThreadPool. But I have to know when the pool have finished all the checks.

There's no signal finished in QThreadPool...

Maybe I do it wrong. Any idea, link or example are welcom !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use QtConcurrent, you should use `QFutureWatcher` to get finished signal.

If it's not possible, you can start another thread and call `pool->waitForDone()` and emit custom signal. Of course this thread must not be in the same pool. Alternatively, you can setup a `QTimer` with small interval and use `bool finished = pool->waitForDone(1);` to periodically check if the pool has been finished.

Comment: I need to use one QFutureWatcher for each Requirement Task on my model. Is it right? And connect each QFutureWatcher::finished to a separatly thread (can be the main thread?)

Comment: Yes. You can connect all watchers to a slot of an object belonging to the main thread.

Comment: So I summarize your suggestion. The base class (abstract) of a Requirement check inherit from QRunnable. My model holds a list of requirement pointers (QList<RequirementTask*>). I create a list of QFutureWatcher, and I watch the states of my tasks. My model has a slot (handleFinished()) that is connects with every QFutureWatcher. When all of them are finished, emit the finishCheck(bool allAccepted) signal to the toolbuttons. What do you think?

Answer (score 0):

When you inherit `QRunnable` yuo can also add inheritance of `QObject` (as first) and emit signal at the end of run.

```
class YourTask : public QObject, public QRunable {
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit YourTask(QObject *parent = 0);

    void run();
};
```

QFutureWatcher is cool when you use future (see another answer).

Comment: I think this is not a good idea for my application design. I have to offer to the other developpers the ability to add new requirement check. The core application have to check the requirement and is responsible of it. With your solution the other developpers have to emit signal when they finish the check. The other developpers don't have to know that the check is run in a separate thread... Am I wrong?

Comment: If you are exposing to other developers API which requires QRunable then you are right (to many compatibility problems may arise). From context I assumed that this part of code is not shared with others.